# Prestashop disable Layout from module

Tags: api, layout, module, prestashop

I've created an API module in prestaShop and I am generating an XML output to a certain CMS page. Thing is that I can't disable the layout. 
I just need to render the XML output from the module *(and no html)*.
Any ideas please? (I am not using the webservice classes)

At least.. Is it possible to do this from a module?

Thanks,
Dan

Answer (score 0):

Override the method "display" of your controller and output whatever you want.

If you do not want to display layout, do not call parent::display().

Answer (score 0):

I have a problem like you. And I knew how to disable it.

You just need add two lines below to your module:

```
$this->display_header = false;
$this->display_footer = false;
```

Example:

```
public function initContent(){
   parent::initContent();
   $this->display_header = false;
   $this->display_footer = false;
   $this->setTemplate('display.tpl');
}
```

Comment: This still includes a `</body></html>` in the end of the page for me.